# Current flow on this branch

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, circuits, circuit-theory

What happens in this current branch? In circuit analysis how to deal with branches like this? [image]

Comment: What branch? have you missed the image?

Comment: I have posted the image

Comment: No current will flow through this branch. Because current flows only in the closed loop.

Comment: @G36 so why this branch is given in the photo

Comment: Because the voltage potential is the same. I.e. the left part of circuit is not floating with respect to the right part of the circuit.

Comment: To be able to have a common point for voltage measurement in a circuit.